# Run a local cluster under a nondefault classloader

Tags: java, classloader, apache-storm

## A Local Cluster from a web classloader

I'm trying to run a local cluster from a web container (yes, it's only for dev & testing purposes) and am having difficulty with classloaders.

### Direct approach

When I do it the easy and [recommended](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Local-mode.html) way,

```
ILocalCluster localCluster = new LocalCluster();
localCluster.submitTopology(topologyName, stormConf, topology);
```

I get rewarded with

```
Async loop died!: java.lang.ClassCastException: my.company.storm.bolt.SomeFilteringBolt cannot be cast to org.apache.storm.task.IBolt
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7953$fn__7966.invoke(executor.clj:787)
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__625.invoke(util.clj:482)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is because the classloader used to load and instantiate the `StormTopology` is an instance of a Jetty `WebAppClassLoader`, but the (sub)process spawned by `LocalCluster.submitTopology()` apparently uses the system classloader. I confirmed this by logging the classloader in the static block of the `SomeFilteringBolt` - the class is indeed loaded twice and the bolt from WebAppCL obviously cannot be cast to a bolt on the system classloader later on.

### Expected behaviour

Now, this is surprising to me as I thought Storm would serialize the `StormTopology` instance, "send" it locally, deserialize it and run it. If it did that, though, it definitely would work. Rather it seems that it's directly using the provided `StormTopology` instance which is problematic under a different classloader.

### What I have tried since

I tried setting these to `true` to force Storm to serialize my topology locally. No change.

- [TOPOLOGY_TESTING_ALWAYS_TRY_SERIALIZE](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/javadocs/org/apache/storm/Config.html#TOPOLOGY_TESTING_ALWAYS_TRY_SERIALIZE)
- and [STORM_LOCAL_MODE_ZMQ](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/javadocs/org/apache/storm/Config.html#STORM_LOCAL_MODE_ZMQ)

I tried running the LocalCluster under the system classloader:

```
ClassLoader originalClassloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

    Config topologyConf = createTopologyConfig();
    Map<String, Object> stormConf = createStormConfig(topologyConf);
    StormTopology topology = createTopology(topologyConf);

    ILocalCluster localCluster = new LocalCluster();
    localCluster.submitTopology(topologyName, stormConf, topology);
} finally {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalClassloader);
}
```

This actually got me a bit further:

```
Thread  died: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at clojure.core__init.__init0(Unknown Source)
    at clojure.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:454)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:330)
    at clojure.lang.Namespace.<init>(Namespace.java:34)
    at clojure.lang.Namespace.findOrCreate(Namespace.java:176)
    at clojure.lang.Var.internPrivate(Var.java:151)
    at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at my.company.storm.LocalTopologyRunner.startTopology(LocalTopologyRunner.java:146)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/refer
    at clojure.lang.Var$Unbound.throwArity(Var.java:43)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.invoke(AFn.java:32)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:467)
    at clojure.lang.RT.<clinit>(RT.java:330)
    ... 18 more
```

Wat?!

### The question

How can I run a Storm topology in local mode safely from a classloader other than the system classloader?

I'm running on Apache Storm 1.0.1, Jetty 8.1, Java 8u112 x64, Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Storm 1.0.3 magically fixed this.

Even without `TOPOLOGY_TESTING_ALWAYS_TRY_SERIALIZE`, even though there's no trace of the fix in the release notes, so I was not able to track it down to a code change. Anyway, we're happy it works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Storm expert at all, but this reminds me of an old "identity crisis" problem i had in the past.

Two things to try:

- Set the priority to the System class loader by calling `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true)`
- If it doesn't work, you can call the methods `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.setSystemClasses` or `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.addSystemClass` to control which classes are considered System classes inside the webapp domain.

Do it for for the whole storm package (it allows wildcards like "org.apache.storm."), before loading them (during the webapp init).

Worth a shot! good luck.

Comment: The first option does unfortunately not work (I had to upgrade and reconfigure a lot of stuff to get there and set it via a system property, what a shame), throws the same errors. And the second option is currently unavailable for me as I don't control the server initialization (locally because the GWT Maven plugin is not very flexible, and on the server because our company's provided Jetty lib is not very flexible, argh). I'll get there, eventually, it just takes time. Will update. Thank you,